# Post-Hoc tests for MANCOVA

Tags: posthoc, manova

:) I am quite new here so I hope I can present my problem in an understandable way:
I conducted the following MANCOVA  and received the output that there is a significant effect on the Independent variable as well as on a covariate (attached the whole code).

But when I try to conduct some **post-hoc tests**, I only receive an error message by R being:

Fehler in mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
Variable(s) ‘OptIn.DE.WGN.1’‘OptIn.DE.WGN.2’‘OptIn.DE.WGN.3’‘OptIn.DE.WGN.4’‘OptIn.DE.WGN.5’ have been specified in ‘linfct’ but cannot be found in ‘model’! **
I don't get why the variables should not be found in the model, as I used the same when conducting my Mancova.

Would appreciate help so much - thanks in advance!!
Best

MAncova Code:
Mancova_Switch_DEU <- manova(cbind(OptOut.DE.WGN.1, OptOut.DE.WGN.2, OptOut.DE.WGN.3, OptOut.DE.WGN.4, OptOut.DE.WGN.5) ~ cbind(OptIn.DE.WGN.1, OptIn.DE.WGN.2, OptIn.DE.WGN.3, OptIn.DE.WGN.4, OptIn.DE.WGN.5) + Anxiety_Avg + Trust + Umfeld + Krankheit + Gesundheitszustand + Respo1 + Respo2 + Respo3 + Alter + Geschlecht + Kinder + Bildung + Religion + FamilyAvg + Altruismus_Avg + Respo1, data = MA_Gesamt_neu)"

IV: cbind(OptIn.DE.WGN.1, OptIn.DE.WGN.2, OptIn.DE.WGN.3, OptIn.DE.WGN.4, OptIn.DE.WGN.5)
(significant) Covariate: Respo3

Post-Hoc test:
posthoc <- glht(Manova_Switch_DEU, linfct = mcp(OptIn.DE.WGN.1 = "Tukey", OptIn.DE.WGN.2 = "Tukey", OptIn.DE.WGN.3 = "Tukey", OptIn.DE.WGN.4 = "Tukey", OptIn.DE.WGN.5 = "Tukey"))

Conduct a Mancova and now try to conduct post-hoc test
--> error message